Can't use SVG in next.js
I have an .svg file in my project which I want to import:
import Logo from "@/assets/logo.svg";
import Image from "next/image";
import MenuIcon from "@/assets/menu.svg";
export const Header = () => {
  return (
    <header className="sticky top-0 backdrop-blur-sm z-20">
      <div className="py-5">
        <div className="container">
          <div className="flex items-center justify-between">
            <Image
              src={Logo}
              alt="Logo"
              width={40}
              height={40}
              className="rounded-lg"
            />
            <MenuIcon className="h-5 w-5 md:hidden" />
            <nav className="hidden md:flex gap-6 text-black/60 items-center">
              <a href="#">About</a>
              <a href="#">Features</a>
              <a href="#">Customers</a>
              <a href="#">Update</a>
              <a href="#">Help</a>
              <button className="bg-black text-white px-4 py-2 rounded-lg font-medium inline-flex align-items justify-center tracking-tight">
                Get for free
              </button>
            </nav>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </header>
  );
};

As you can see in the code, I have 2 svg files (menu & logo) the menu works fine but the logo.svg throws an error:

Error: Functions cannot be passed directly to Client Components unless you explicitly expose it by marking it with "use server". Or maybe you meant to call this function rather than return it.

I have tried use client - the error goes but the image doesn't show although the .svg file works fine in my browser..
Also I have already installed svgr/webpack and next.config.mjs seems fine
/** @type {import('next').NextConfig} */
const nextConfig = {
  webpack(config) {
    // Grab the existing rule that handles SVG imports
    const fileLoaderRule = config.module.rules.find((rule) =>
      rule.test?.test?.(".svg")
    );

    config.module.rules.push(
      // Reapply the existing rule, but only for svg imports ending in ?url
      {
        ...fileLoaderRule,
        test: /\.svg$/i,
        resourceQuery: /url/, // *.svg?url
      },
      // Convert all other *.svg imports to React components
      {
        test: /\.svg$/i,
        issuer: fileLoaderRule.issuer,
        resourceQuery: { not: [...fileLoaderRule.resourceQuery.not, /url/] }, // exclude if *.svg?url
        use: ["@svgr/webpack"],
      }
    );

    // Modify the file loader rule to ignore *.svg, since we have it handled now.
    fileLoaderRule.exclude = /\.svg$/i;

    return config;
  },

  // ...other config
};

export default nextConfig;


Just add images to public directory, and use in image tag directly with path for example <img src="/images/svg/my.svg"

It is not possible to import a svg from any location like you are trying.
You have three options:

use a HTML <img> tag and reference the svg-url there. You have to serve the svg-file somewhere, usually you include it in your public directory. That is the easiest way if you are only dealing with static svg images.
use the next/image component. This is a component implementation of an HTML <img> with some additional functionality, but ultimately it boils down to an <img>. So the svg you are referencing still needs to be served somwhere. In the case of the image component it is /public/images. You would need to put the logo in that directory and import it like import Logo from "@/public/images/logo.svg".
most flexible: turn the svg into a component. Tools like SVGR will do the hard work and convert your svg source code into a component. Then you can use the component directly like <Logo>. If you want to add additional props the <svg> tag can't handle, you will have to implement them yourself, but it will also give you acces to all elements of the svg and you can manipulate it programatically in any way. With that solution the svg source code is part of the component and does not need to be served statically.


You can create your own logo components (using outside tools such as svg viewer to create your component and copy/paste.
I create a special icons.tsx file for all of my icons, typing and exporting them all in one place:
//components/ui/icons.tsx

type IconProps = React.SVGProps<SVGSVGElement>

export function ExampleIcon(props: IconProps) {
  return (
    <svg
      xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
      width="16"
      height="16"
      viewBox="0 0 16 16"
      { ...props }
    >
    <text>
      <textPath>{":)"}</textPath>
    </text>
  </svg>
  )
}

Additionally, you can create an index.ts file for the icons in @/components/ui if you want to keep them in one place:
//components/ui/index.ts

export * from './icons'

// or export {ExampleIcon} from './icons'

Having control over your code is a bonus if you ask me. You're able to directly make any optimizations before it's time to compile.
In any case, I hope this helps. Happy coding :)
